# How to use different colors for each select2 option?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I'm using a select2 dropdown, and would like to set different colours on each options.

Example:

```html
<select class="select2" name="fruit">
  <option class="red-option">Apple</option>
  <option class="green-option">Kiwi</option>
  <option class="blue-option">Grape</option>
</select>
```

I can colourize the rendered, selected option as follow:

```css
.select2-selection__rendered[title="Apple"] {
  color: red !important;
}
```

How to also colourize the options in the select2 dropdown - either based on the option class ('red-option') or value ('Apple')?

PS: I use bootstrap 3.3 + jQuery and don't mind using JS to do this if I must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.

Select2 generates an id attribute for all the dropdown options, using the parent `select`'s `name` attribute.

With my example, I was able to apply a colour using :nth-child(x) as follow:

```css
.select2-results__options[id*="select2-fruits"] .select2-results__option:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}
.select2-results__options[id*="select2-fruits"] .select2-results__option:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
}
.select2-results__options[id*="select2-fruits"] .select2-results__option:nth-child(3) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select class="select2" name="fruit">
    <option class="red-option">Apple</option>
    <option class="green-option">Kiwi</option> 
    <option class="blue-option">Grape</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't find this answer as the correct one: what is the point having different classes to to the options if you use nth-child??? and in this way, if the options are not ordered you will still not achieve your goal

Answer (score 14):

I found a better solution using the options

```
function formatState(state) {
  const option = $(state.element);
  const color = option.data("color");

  if (!color) {
    return state.text;
  }

  return $(`<span style="color: ${color}">${state.text}</span>`);
};

jQuery(node).select2({
  templateResult: formatState,
  templateSelection: formatState,
});
```

The color comes from the html data attribute in my case

```
<option style="color: #F00" data-color="#F00" value="1">Red Option</option>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked beautifully for styling individual options where class="red" didn't work.

Comment: I have one small request. I have tried using the same code and it works fine, the only problems is it just colors the text I need the whole background for that particular item to change its color. background-color style attribute only works for that text background.  I have tried using status.text.select2.parent.addClass() to get the <li> item to change its background color but it doesn't work. Can anyone please help.

Comment: I used option.addClass("someclass") which actually worked but it still doesn't completely color the <li> element and also when I select the color option it doesn't show in the select control as selected instead it shows blank. 
option.parent().addClass() doesn't work either. Styling is not my strong ability, and programming after a 5 year gap so kindly please help me out.

Comment: Thanks man with this solution I can now add html to option witch is not possible to do in a normal option ! very useful answer !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS attribute selector like so on select2-results__option elements:

```js
$(".select2").select2();
```

```css
.select2-selection__rendered[title="Apple"] {
  color: red !important;
}

.select2-results__option[id*="Apple"] {
  color: red;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2" name="fruit">
  <option class="red-option">Apple</option>
  <option class="green-option">Kiwi</option>
  <option class="blue-option">Grape</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The `id` attribute give to the results options are using the `select`'s `name` attribute, instead of the `option`s attribute. In my example, the `id` that select2 applies to `.select2-results__option` is something like **`select2-fruits-a0-result-rh69-1`**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple and generic approach to adding a class to select2 options:

```js
$('.select2').select2({
    // render html in the dropdown
    templateResult: function(el) { return '<span class="' + ($(el.element).prop('class') || '') + '">' + el.text + '</span>'; },
    // render html for the selected option
    templateSelection: function(el) { return '<span class="' + ($(el.element).prop('class') || '') + '">' + el.text + '</span>'; },
    // render html as-is without escaping it
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; }
});
```

This way the select2 options will inherit any class you add to your options.