# How to change the background of each select2 option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 for a dropdown selection box and I'm trying to change the background color of the options. There would be a separate color for each option. I've tried by adding a style attribute to the options but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" id="select-tags" name="usertags" multiple="multiple">
        {% for tag in userTags %}
        <option value="{{ tag }}" data-id="{{ tag.color }}" style="background-color:{{ tag.color }}" class="options">{{ tag }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

$('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
```

Comment: Please attach your code

Comment: I've added the code but it won't be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding background colors to the `<option>` elements inside your `<select>` isn't working because those elements end up hidden. Select2 hides the original `<select>`, then generates its own elements to produce a styled "fake" select control which mirrors the value of the hidden "real" one.

[image: Notice the "aria-hidden" attribute on the select element]

Since select2 doesn't provide an API for passing color values to individual options, you'll need to try either using `nth-child()` selectors in CSS or some extra javascript to style the fake option elements that select2 creates. [Here's a question from 2018 with answers demonstrating each approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801609/how-to-use-different-colors-for-each-select2-option)

Comment: Is there a way that I can see the generated HTML for the dropdown options from select2?

Comment: Sure! If you're using Chrome or Firefox (or Safari with the Develop menu enabled), right-click on the select2 dropdown in your page and click "Inspect Element." You'll then be able to explore the DOM and see everything, including javascript-generated HTML.

Comment: I've search for it in Inspect but I couldn't find it. Then I took a look at the docs and saw that it was generated at the bottom of the DOM.